# Get ID of a div while clicking

Tags: ajax, click

First sorry if my English is bad I am french x)
So I have an issue with something. 
I want to get the ID of the div which I clicked on. Here's my script :

Data sent with PHP thanks to AJAX :

$id = $donnees['id'];

```
echo '<div class="message" id="'. $id. '">';
    echo '<div class="sanction"><div class="bannir"><img src="img/ban.png" alt="ban" class="ban"></div>';
    echo '<div class="supprimer"><img src="img/sup.png" alt="supprimer" class="sup"></div></div>';
    echo '<div class="pseudo">' .$donnees['pseudo']. '</div>';
    echo '<div class="contenu">' .$message.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
```

Jquery :

```
$('#display').on('click', '.supprimer', function(){
    var id = (this).parent().attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

I don't know if you understand what I want, but if someone has an idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).prop('id');
```

to get the id property.

Comment: with var id = $(this).parent().parent().prop('id'); it works thank a lot !